# ffprobe seems to have strange tag outputs

Tags: mp3, ffprobe

I used id3tag to tag some MP3 files. Afterwards, ffprobe does not read them correctly.  I'm not sure if this is an ffprobe issue, or otherwise.
Anyone seen anything like this?

```
$ id3v2 -l  01\ Trust\ Game.mp3
id3v1 tag info for 01 Trust Game.mp3:
Title  : Trust Game                      Artist: Toadies
Album  : Feeler                          Year: 2010, Genre: Unknown (255)
Comment:                                 Track: 1
id3v2 tag info for 01 Trust Game.mp3:
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Trust Game
TRCK (Track number/Position in set): 1/9
TPOS (Part of a set): 1/1
TCON (Content type): Rock (17)
APIC (Attached picture): ()[, 3]: image/jpeg, 118146 bytes
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
TYER (Year): 2010
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Toadies
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Feeler
```

ffprobe shows this:

```
$ ffprobe 01\ Trust\ Game.mp3
ffprobe version 6.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
[some config omitted]
Input #0, mp3, from '01 Trust Game.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : ▒吀爀甀猀琀 䜀愀洀攀
    track           : ▒㄀⼀㤀
    disc            : 1/1
    genre           : ▒刀漀挀欀

    album           : Feeler
    artist          : Toadies
    date            : 2010
```